# Set SNMP Community with check_mk WATO

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I'm using check_mk with WATO on an Ubuntu server running Open Monitoring Distribution 1.0. So far, so good!

I'm trying to configure the snmp community for check_mk to pull info from some of our HP switches. On our switches that have the community set to public, it can pull just fine (I'd like to change the community, hence the question).

http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_wato_using.html describes making sure you've set your community correctly, but doesn't give info on how to do it.

http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_snmp.html describes how to set the community when you use the main.mk file to define your hosts, but since I added all hosts with WATO, my main.mk file is nearly blank.

Is there a place to change the snmp community in WATO for check_mk? Other methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under 'WATO Configuration' on the left pane go to :

`Host & Service Parameters ==> Access to Agents ==> SNMP ==> SNMP communities of monitored host`

Then click on the 'Create rule in Folder' ==> 'Edit rule'.

You can use the 'Explicit hosts' option to specify hosts.

Comment: Awesome! That did it. Thank you. Totally not where I was looking.